# Why can't Visual Studio 2010 Native C++ project do auto-completion?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Professional and a native (non-CLR) C++ project. I can not get auto-member-completion, auto parameter list, or any other intellisense related feature to work.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled the entire product, which is not a small task, yet still it refuses to work. I believe all the settings are at their defaults except some changes to the editor's colors.

Does anyone have any clue as to how I can get autocomplete working like it did in Visual Studio 2008?

EDIT: I created a native C++ console app and intellesense is working, for now. Who knowns when it will stop or why? My original project still has the issue. Is the problem program size? Number of lines of code? Number of files in the project? Including ATL headers? Orientation of the moon?

Comment: check this out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/466dd46e-993f-4856-9aa5-41d8bd9c6a52

Comment: try tools/options/text editor/C++ and look around there. I'm not placing this as an answer for the reason that I've also had this problem with VS2010 and it just started working for me after I've created new project. Over all it has to be said that VS2010 is much slower than 2008 and response time is lower that it use to be so "more patience" when dealing with "IntelliSense".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not necessarily the best way to fix this, but try installing a visual studio extension like visual assist, which enhances syntax highlighting. It might just help

Comment: Hmmm. One would expect MS products to function as advertised without having to purchase third party addons. I try and avoid addons because they just add more runtime code to an already bloated and slow process. Thanks though.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, SP1 beta is out, and though I have not tried it, you might give it a try. MS people have knack for listening to developers concerns such as this... might save the day for you.

Answer (score -1):

They dropped this feature due to lack of time. Complain [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/501921/c-cli-intellisense#details).

Comment: No. They dropped C++/CLR intellisense. This is a non-CLR project.